# Templates. Parameter pack expansion - remap types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Is it possible to remap types in the list we would get during parameter pack expansion?

Assume we have next types, that we want to use as template arguments:

```
struct A {
    typedef char type;
};

struct B {
    typedef float type;
};

struct C {
    typedef void* type;
};
```

And here is class template:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Foo {
    // after expansion should be
    // void bar(Arg0::type, Arg1::type, Arg2::type, ...)
    void bar(/* expand Args here */) {}
};
```

In what way we should expand `Args` to get `Foo::bar(Arg0::type, Arg1::type, Arg2::type, ...)`?

```
Foo<A, B, C> f;
// now there should be method void f::bar(A::type, B::type, C::type)
f.bar('a', 1.f, nullptr);
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly straightforward:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Foo {
    void bar(typename Args::type... a) {}
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f68115f355d74a)

---

[opinion-based]

Note that this is a good reason not to name parameter packs using plurals; all uses of the parameter pack are actually written such that the pack name represents a *single element* of the pack, and expansion happens using `...`.

[/opinion-based]